# Abstraction as a definition

Tags: oop, abstraction

I am trying to understand the basic OOP concept called *abstraction*. When I say "understand", I mean not just to learn a definition, but really have a deep understanding.

On the internet, I have seen many definitions such as:

> Hiding the low level implementation and providing high level specification

and

> focusing on essential qualities rather than specific examples.

I understand that the iPhone button is a great example of abstraction, since I, as a user, don't have to know how the screen is displayed, all I have to know is to press the button.

What do you think of the following conclusion, when it comes to abstraction:

> Abstraction takes many specific instances of objects and extracts their common information and functions by providing a single, generalised concept.

So based on this, a class is actually an abstraction of many instances, right?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with both of your examples. An iPhone button is not an abstraction of the screen, it is an interface to use the phone. A class is also not an abstraction of its instances.

An abstraction can be thought of treating a specific concept as a form of a more general concept.

To repeat an overused example: all vehicles can move. Cars rotate wheels, airplanes use jets, trains run on tracks.

Given a collection of vehicles, instead of being burdened with knowing the specifics of each vehicles' inner workings, and having to:

```
car.RotateWheel();
airplane.StartJet();
train.MoveOnTrack();
```

we could treat these objects as the more abstract `vehicle`, and tell them to

```
vehicle.Move();
```

In this case `vehicle` is an **abstraction**. It does not represent any specific object, but represents the common functionality of cars, airplanes and trains and allows us to interact with these specific objects without knowing anything about them except that they are a type of `vehicle`.

In the context of OOP, `vehicle` would most likely be a base class of the more specific types of vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there are actually 2 underlying concepts that needs to be understood here.

1. Abstraction: The idea of dealing only with "What" of something rather than "How" of something. For example: When you call an object method you only care about what the method does and not how it does what it does. There are layers of abstraction i.e the upper layer is only interested in what the below layer does and not how it does it. Another example: When you are writing assembly instruction you only care what a particular instruction does and not how the underlying circuit in the CPU execute the instruction.
2. Generalization: The idea of comparing a bunch of things (objects, functions, basically anything) and figure out the commonality between them and then extracting that commonality. A class with a bunch of properties is the generalization of the instances of the classes as all the instances have the same properties but different values for those properties.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of object-oriented programming is to take the real-world thinking into software development as much as possible. That is, *abstraction* means what any dictionary may define.

For example, one of possible definitions of *abstraction* [in Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abstraction):

> The quality of dealing with ideas rather than events.

[WordReference.com's definition](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/abstraction) is even more eloquent:

> the act of considering something as a general quality or characteristic, apart from concrete realities, specific objects, or actual instances.

In fact, WordReference.com's one is one of possible definitions of *abstraction* and you should be surprised because it's not a programming explanation of *abstraction*.

Perhaps you want a more programming alike definition of *abstraction*, and I'll try to provide a good summary:

*Abstraction is the process of turning concrete realities into object representations which could be used as archetypes. Usually, in most OOP languages, archetypes are represented by types which in turn could be defined by classes, structures and interfaces. Types may abstract data or behaviors.*

One good example of abstraction would be that a chair made of oak wood **is still a chair**. That's the way our mind works. You learn that certain forms are the most basic definition of many things. Your brain doesn't see all details of a given chair, but it sees that it fulfills the requirements to consider something *a chair*. Object-oriented programming and abstraction just mirrors this.